# The state does not appear to change immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { editZoneMaster } from "../../../redux/actions/GeneralMaster/ZoneMaster";
export default function ModalForm() {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    open: false
  });
  const UI = useSelector(state => state.UI);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      open: true
    });
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      open: false
    });
  };
  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editZoneMaster(formData));
    console.log(UI.errors)
    console.log(Object.keys(UI.errors).length)
    if (Object.keys(UI.errors).length === 0) handleClose();
  };
```

**Console output:**

[image: Output from my console]

I'm trying to validate my form, to prevent user from closing the modal if any errors are detected. On the first submit errors are not getting logged, only on the second submit they are. The state is being changed correctly. Also while returning the errors it runs well. But not on render.

Comment: Can you share the code of redux?

Answer (score 0):

Logging the state right after dispatching won't show you the new state since dispatching actions is asynchronous, i.e. it takes time to affect the state (usually a short amount of time).

To track changes in your object, you should use the `useEffect` hook, like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(UI.errors);
    console.log(Object.keys(UI.errors).length);
}, [ UI.errors ]);
```

(and remove the console.log calls from handleSubmit)

Answer (score 0):

It is because UI will change only in the next render. There is no magic binding where the UI value changes are reflected immediately after the dispatch. If you wanted to get the validated value immedediately after dispatch you need to use useStore hook (https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usestore), and something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch, useStore } from "react-redux";
import { editZoneMaster } from "../../../redux/actions/GeneralMaster/ZoneMaster";
export default function ModalForm() {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    open: false
  });
  const UI = useSelector(state => state.UI);
  const store = useStore();
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      open: true
    });
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      open: false
    });
  };
  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editZoneMaster(formData));
    const updatedUI = store.getState().UI; // this is now updated UI state
    console.log(updatedUI.errors)
    console.log(Object.keys(updatedUI.errors).length)
    if (Object.keys(updatedUI.errors).length === 0) handleClose();
  };
```

But honestly I like this approach better (more clean in my opinion):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch, useStore } from "react-redux";
import { editZoneMaster } from "../../../redux/actions/GeneralMaster/ZoneMaster";
export default function ModalForm() {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    open: false
  });
  const UI = useSelector(state => state.UI);

 useEffect(() => {        
    console.log(UI.errors)
    console.log(Object.keys(UI.errors).length)
    if (Object.keys(UI.errors).length === 0) handleClose();}, [setState, UI]);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      open: true
    });
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      open: false
    });
  };
  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editZoneMaster(formData));
  };
```

Where you check for validation and close the UI after it changed. Both solutions are valid.

Hope this helps.